# ¿Cómo puedo borrar en Linux archivos anteriores a una fecha determinada indicada en el nombre de los archivos?

Tags: linux, regex, bash, shell, ksh

Necesito borrar todos los archivos anteriores a una determinada fecha que viene en el nombre del fichero.

Este es un ejemplo de nombre de fichero:

```
20170822_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz
```

Necesitaría, en este caso, borrar todos los ficheros anteriores a `20170822`.

¿Sabéis cómo podría realizarlo en Linux?

Comment: ¿Ese nombre de archivo lo tienes ya en una variable o lo pasas como parámetro al script que quieres ejecutar? Veo etiquetas bash y ksh, ¿puedo usar bash?

Comment: Hola Muyhomeless. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio. Aqui se resuelven dudas trabajadas previamente. Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte sobre eso¿ Explica tambien por qué lo intentado no ha funcionado. Si no has intentado nada, has de investigar e intentar imlementarlo. Para más informacion tiene [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Utilizas las etiquetas Ksh y Bash. ¿Con cuál de las dos trabajas? Son mutuamente excluyentes :)

Answer (score 7):

Lo más simple sería utilizar la fecha de creación del fichero. Sin embargo, no parece que se pueda utilizar. Por tanto, toca extraer información del nombre del archivo.

Podrías realizar la búsqueda con `find` y usar algún tipo de expresión regular mediante `-regex`, pero probablemente sea más fácil utilizar una pura comparación, pues las fechas están puestas de modo que se pueden comparar numéricamente: todo número de la forma XXXXXXXX (8 dígitos) menor que 20170822 corresponde a una fecha anterior al 22 de agosto de 2017, y viceversa.

Por tanto, puedes utilizar:

```
for file in *
do
    if [[ $file =~ ^([0-9]{8})_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz$ ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} < 20170822 )); then
        echo "elimino $file"
        #rm "$file"  # <-- a eliminar una vez se confirma que funciona
    fi
done
```

Donde `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` devuelve el contenido capturado en `([0-9]{8})`. Es decir, la fecha del archivo.

Se podría simplificar el `for` haciendo uso de la expansión que proporciona `*` combinada con el patrón fijo "_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz":

```
for file in *_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz
```

pero de todas formas el `if [[ $file =~ ^([0-9]{8})_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz$ ]]`  se debe mantener para así poder extraer la fecha del nombre del archivo.

Referencias útiles:

- [Uso de BASH_REMATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150419/1983854)
- [Validar si una cadena coincide con una expresión regular en Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112809/1983854)

Comment: Excelente aporte no conocía BASH_REMATCH. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esta podría ser otra alternativa usando [Substring Replacement](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz;do
     (( ${file/_hadoop_bckp.tar.gz/} < 20170822 )) && echo rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: Muy bien visto este reemplazo (eliminación) de subcadena, limpio y eficaz.